# Customise menu bar icons

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I'm looking to spice up Mojave a bit by adding colour to menu bar icons. Namely Wi-Fi and Battery icons.

/System/Library/CoreServices/MenuExtras/Battery.menu/Contents/Resources and found the following files:

**UPSCharged.pdf -
UPSCharging.pdf -
UPSEmpty.pdf -
UPSLevelBlack.pdf -
UPSLevelRed.pdf**

Having disabled System Integrity Protection and updated permissions to allow me to edit/replace these files, the menu bar icons remain unchanged.

Is there a way to recompile or alter these running icons once I’ve changed the files I believe have those icons?

Comment: How about a restart?

Comment: Multiple restarts. Has no effect